# Is a concentration check required for each of my following spells if I buff myself with Mage Armor

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spellcasting

Player's Handbook 1, p. 170, "Concentration" - "Spell" says:

"If you are affected by a spell while attempting to cast a spell of your own, you must make a Concentration check or lose the spell you are casting."

Now I have the feeling I played DnD wrong for years - this means if I buff myself with e.g. "Mage Armor" and try to cast "Magic Missiles" the next round, I have to do a concentration check, correct? And someone I buff with another spell, too?

There is no mentioning of the spell affecting me being from someone else or hostile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## You've not been playing wrong

What the question quotes is a subsection of the section [Concentration](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#concentration) that, in part, says, "If something **interrupts** your concentration while you’re casting, you must make a Concentration check or lose the spell" (*Player's Handbook* 170 and emphasis mine). Typically, turn 1's casting of the [*mage armor*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsMtoO.html#mage-armor) spell can't interrupt turn 2's casting of the [*magic missile*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsMtoO.html#magic-missile) spell.

That is, when a wizard finishes casting the *mage armor* spell, the wizard is, indeed, affected by the *mage armor* spell, but on the wizard's next turn that same now-ongoing and already-been-cast *mage armor* spell doesn't interrupt the wizard's casting of another spell. Getting a new spell on him in the middle of casting the *magic missile* spell would be a concern because then that's an interruption, but no interruption is typically caused by the spells that are already present on the caster.

For instance, if the *mage armor* spell were cast on the wizard at the same time as the wizard was casting a *magic missile* spell then a Concentration skill check (DC = the *mage armor* spell's saving throw DC) would be required. (Doing this typically requires the caster of the *mage armor* spell to ready an action.)

The Concentration subsection Spells is telling casters that it's not only weapon damage and the environment that can interrupt casting spells but also that spells can interrupt the casting spells, too.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I think as a non-native speaker, I mixed up "affect" and "effect" - the "Mage Armor" spell affects me when I cast it, but what I experience later is the effect of the spell.

Comment: @Blutkoete Don't feel bad about that, even most native speakers (myself included) mix up "affect" and "effect" all the time.

Comment: _"if the mage armor spell were cast on the wizard at the same time as the wizard was casting a magic missile spell then a Concentration skill check ... would be required."_ - Oh - really? I would have thought the entry "distracted by a nondamaging spell" relates only to spells that attack the caster.

Comment: @PeregrinTook So far as I can tell, the game doesn't make that distinction, although the DM totally can. I can imagine that, even were you warned first, being told to voluntarily forego a saving throw against—and accept the results of—someone else's spell that you think is probably a *mage armor* spell (whether because that's what you're told or because your Spellcraft skill check is high enough) while you're in the middle of casting your own *magic missile* spell in combat would, in fact, be distracting. But, like the answer says, it's a really rare scenario, anyway.

Comment: But casting a spell with a casting time of 1 round can easily get you into trouble, if you are distracted by _every_ spell that affects you. Let's say you cast Summon Monster while your allies cast spells like Prayer, Haste etc on the party. ... - not a very rare scenario ...

Comment: @PeregrinTook It's been a rare scenario in my campaigns. Is initiative order kept secret in your campaigns? Because worst case would be for a wizard to start casting a *summon* or *enlarge person* spell and, before he finishes, all 3 other party members cast buff spells. Why didn't the wizard just delay? The only reason I can imagine that happening is secret initiative order or miscommunication.

Comment: No, we don't play with a secret initiative order but we also never played with that rule that your ally's spells can distract you. So I don't really know. You're probably right and it's a rather rare thing. I will think about introducing this rule in our group. Might lead to some funny "you can't cast that now, don't you see that I'm just casting this"-siuations ... :)